# Does Samsung galaxy tab pro 10.1 support exFAT on the SD card?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10

Does this tablet support exFAT file system on micro SD card? Can this tablet recognize micro SD card formatted with exFAT file system?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as indicated on the user manual. I'm currently using a Sandisk Class 4 32GB formatted with exFAT, works just fine. Stock ROM, unrooted.

Answer (score -1):

Just format everything to FAT32.
Your mobile,flashdrive and PS4 all just format to FAT32.
Format everything to FAT32 the best.
For example:You use FAT32 files from PS4 to FAT32 flashdrive(5GB),then you transfer the files in your flashdrive to my mobile(ExFat and FAT32) driver.
The transfer will be exactly 5GB,because FAT32 and FAT32 has no side effect of expansion of files.
Beside,adding FAT32 to your mobile is very cheap.
Just pay $1 to $2 and you will have no issue in the future.

It is very likely that Samsung Tablet use EXFAT,because it exceed 32GB in it's memory slot.
I am refering to Memory card.
To prevent expansion of files,I add FAT32 to my Samsung Tab.
Beside,it is so cheap.

Pay less than $2 and you can forgot about all worries.
Let say one day........
You tranfer 5GB of files to your flashdrive and then transfer it into your mobile,which is EXFAT.
But,the EXFAT expand your files to 10+GB.
When you tranfer the files to your flashdrive and then transfer it to your PS4,you can't save all the data to your PS4.

http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/hardware-clinic-2/exfat-take-up-more-space-than-fat32-4746802.html

Just set everything to the same format and if it is less than $2.
Just buy the add on.

In the future,you don't need to worry which porn video in your mobile must you delete.You don't need to delete some of your PS4 games to make space for your data.

Comment: What has a PS4 got to do with anything? And where do you get this idea about paying $2?