# What should I do to use my hard drive on a Samsung Tablet?

Tags: ntfs, tablet

I have a 2 TB hard drive full of movies.  I am getting bored watching movies on the computer so I decided buy a Samsung Galaxy Tab.  My hard drive is NTFS and my friends told me that I have to convert NTFS to exFAT to able to see my files on the tablet.  My question is, if I convert my hard drive from NTFS to exFAT, will I be able to watch the files on the tablet?  If not, what should I do to be able to do so?

Comment: How are you connecting the hard drive?  If it's connected to a computer already, it would likely be easiest to access it via SMB over Wi-Fi.  Unless the files are massive or your router very slow, playback should work fine.

Comment: i am connecting hard drive to tab with usb but tab does not recognise my hard drive and my friend told me that i have to convert it. i am asking if it is true or not.

Comment: I would try connecting a USB thumb drive formatted in those different formats first to see if your tab recognizes either, before I wiped my hard drive.  I agree with @Matthew Read that accessing it over a network is a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

[The Galaxy Tab appears to support exFAT](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/64392/1465), so yes — you could back up your files, format the drive, and restore the files.  Then the connection should work.

If you are rooted, there are ways to mount NTFS drives directly.  [Paragon Mounther](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paragon.mounter) should be able to do so.